# Get position of click within text (non-input)

Tags: javascript, html, click

**Goal: get text position of a click within non-input elements (spans/divs) with IE11**

I have a workbench for users to add and modify content using widgets. There is a main widget that has a list of different types of content, for example it might have something like:

```
<div class='summaryView'>
    <div class='summaryHead'>Summary 1</div>
    <div class='summaryContent'>Foo bar baz</div>
</div>
```

A user would click within this and it would open up another widget in which the summary content would be within a textarea (actually a codemirror instance). A new requirement is that if the user clicks between the `a` and `b` in `bar` (for example), when the widget opens up for them to start editing content, the cursor would be in that same place.

The issue I'm having with doing this is knowing the actual position they clicked. I can get the coordinates from the event... but this doesn't really help me (unless maybe I used a monospace font, which is not an option).

I also found `document.caretPositionFromPoint` and `document.caretRangeFromPoint` which seemed helpful... and I could do something like:

```
if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
    range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    textNode = range.offsetNode;
    offset = range.offset;

} else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    textNode = range.startContainer;
    offset = range.startOffset;
}
```

...and then go from there... Except these are not working for IE11 (which my users are unfortunately stuck with).

Even though [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/caretPositionFromPoint) seems to indicate it should work with IE. I'm assuming it has something to do with "This is an experimental technology".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to piece some stuff together and come up with this which seems to be working for me in IE11, giving me the parentElement and the text offset of the click:

```
if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange ();
    range.moveToPoint (event.clientX, event.clientY);
    var end = Math.abs( range.duplicate().moveEnd('character', -1000000) );
    var rDup = range.duplicate();
    range.collapse( false );
    var parentElement = rDup.parentElement();
    var children = parentElement.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rDup.moveToElementText( children[i] );
        if ( rDup.inRange(range) ) {
            parentElement = children[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    rDup.moveToElementText( parentElement );
    var offset = end - Math.abs( rDup.moveStart('character', -1000000) );
}
```